# Website (vinted.fr) hidding data when I'm trying to connect with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

So I've changed to sum up my problem, as requested in comment (sorry, I'm begininng with stackoverflow also).

So here's my problem. If you browse [this link to vinted.fr](https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=), you should see many announces. But if you browse this site using the scrapy, for example with the following command :

```
scrapy shell https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=
view(response)
```

You won't see the announces.

I thought it was due to the User-Agent, so I set the following code in my *settings.py* :

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
```

But it did nothing. Do you have any solution ? Or any documentation that could help to read about that please ?

Comment: There are already plenty of resources available on the subject, and this is likely too broad/vague. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I've tried to change my post, I hope it's more clear and it fits more with the stackoverflow standards. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Actually the announces are in the HTML in a format that is easy to scrape

```
"entity":{"id":478712497,"title":"Sac à bandoulière Guess ","brand_id":20,"size_id":null,"status_id":2,"disposal_conditions":4,"user_id":26467312,"owner_id":null,"country_id":16,"catalog_id":158,"color1_id":1,"color2_id":12,"package_size_id":1,"is_hidden":0,"is_reserved":0,"reserved_for_user_id":null,"is_visible":1,"is_unisex":0,"is_closed":0,"is_admin_alerted":false,"active_bid_count":0,"favourite_count":1,"view_...
```

you can use regex to find each product `json`,then extract what you want.

Comment: But my problem is that these announces are not present when I'm connecting with scrapy. The page retrieved by scrapy does not contain the announces :(

Comment: yes, they are you just search in page source. you will find the dictionary form (JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the project **[Vinted-data](https://github.com/0AlphaZero0/Vinted-data)**. I am using it to extract data from **[Vinted.fr](https://www.vinted.fr/)**.

`Scrapy` is not always the good solution and you will have to get your hands dirty, using `regex` or other methods.